# I cant build my project because of this specific error

Tags: ios, swift

Undefined symbol: _$s8LinkmDev19AccountDetailsModelC26totalBalanceForInstallmentSdSgvg

This is what i get when I want to build the project, I thought that is because oftotalBalanceForInstallment variable inside AccoutnDetailsModel but it does not have that variable or even any kind of errors in file. This the file.

```swift
import Foundation

enum AccountStatus: String {
    typealias RawValue = String
    
    case active = "ACTIVE"
    case blocked = "BLOCKED"
    
    static func displayName(for status: String) -> String {
        if let status = AccountStatus(rawValue: status) {
            switch status {
            case .active:
                return LnKeys.accountDetailsStatusActive.localized
            case .blocked:
                return LnKeys.accountDetailsStatusNotActive.localized
            }
        }
        
        return Constants.emptyValue
    }
    
}

class AccountDetailsModel {
    var accountOwner: String?
    var currentBalance: Double?
    var totalBalance: Double?
    var reservedTransactions: Double?
    var interestRate: Double?
    var overdraft: Double?
    var overdraftExpiry: Date?
    var accountStatus: String?
    var rejectedOrders: Double?
    var overdraftInterestRate: Double?
    var accountID: String?
    var toSignOrders: Double?
    var accountName: String?
    var completedOrders: Double?
    var currency: String
    var cardTransactions: Double?
    var ordersLater: Double?
    var accountTypeName: String?
    var accountLimit: Double?
    var validateDateLimitFrom: Date?
    var validateDateLimitTo: Date?
    
    init(data: [String: Any]) {
        self.accountOwner = data["accountOwner"] as? String
        self.currentBalance = data["currentBalance"] as? Double
        self.totalBalance = data["totalBalance"] as? Double
        self.reservedTransactions = data["reservedTransactions"] as? Double
        self.interestRate = data["interestRate"] as? Double
        self.overdraft = data["overdraft"] as? Double
        self.overdraftExpiry = DateFormatter.format(withType: .serverDate).date(from: data["overdraftExpiry"] as? String ?? "")
        self.accountStatus = data["accountStatus"] as? String
        self.rejectedOrders = data["rejectedOrders"] as? Double
        self.overdraftInterestRate = data["overdraftInterestRate"] as? Double
        self.accountID = data["accountId"] as? String
        self.toSignOrders = data["toSignOrders"] as? Double
        self.accountName = data["accountName"] as? String
        self.completedOrders = data["completedOrders"] as? Double
        self.currency = data["currency"] as? String ?? ""
        self.cardTransactions = data["cardTransactions"] as? Double
        self.ordersLater = data["ordersLater"] as? Double
        self.accountTypeName = data["accountType"] as? String
        self.accountLimit = data["accountLimit"] as? Double
        self.validateDateLimitFrom = DateFormatter.format(withType: .serverDate).date(from: data["validateDateLimitFrom"] as? String ?? "")
        self.validateDateLimitTo = DateFormatter.format(withType: .serverDate).date(from: data["validateDateLimitTo"] as? String ?? "")
    }
}
```

I changed the branch back and it still has that same error and I do not understand what is the error and where it comes from.

Comment: Clean/Removed derived data?

Comment: It worked, thank You!